# Php variable error in loop

Tags: php, loops

Its me again....

```
for ($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($ergebnis);$j++)
            {
                echo '<table class="center_me table_styled table_inline">';
                echo '<tr class="full fill_me">'; 
                echo "\t<td>" . mysql_field_name($ergebnis, $j) ."</td>\n";
                echo '</tr>';
                while($zeile = mysql_fetch_row($ergebnis))
                {
                    echo '<tr class="full">';
                    echo "<td>".$zeile[$j]."</td>\n";
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                echo '</table>';
            }
```

In this PHP script $j counts in the for loop, but in the while loop $j is always 0 and the while part just got execute one time....

(And yes i need to split the tables like this.... TABLE 1 = FIELDNAME1
                                                            FIELDATA1
                                                            FIELDDATA2
                                                            ......
  TABLE 2 = FIELDNAME2
            FIELDATA1
            FIELDDATA2
            ......

Old Script:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>

            <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM Kunden;";   
                $ergebnis = mysql_query($query);    

                for ($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($ergebnis); $j++)
                {
                    echo "\t<td>" . mysql_field_name($ergebnis, $j) ."</td>\n";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>

            <?php       
                while ($zeile = mysql_fetch_row($ergebnis))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";    
                    for ($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($ergebnis); $j++)
                    {
                        echo "<td>" . $zeile[$j] . "</td>\n";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>\n\n";
                }
                mysql_free_result($ergebnis);
            ?>  
    </table>
```

Comment: die you dump mysql_num_fields($ergebnis)? are you sure it's bigger than 1?

Comment: Yes im sure.... Because if i use an other script which create the table for one table it works perfectly... (I will edit my post)

Comment: ok and how can i fix this? (Im a php noob :/ )

Comment: Ok but i think u missunderstood me ... i need to put every vertical line in a singel <table>.... Not all in one... So my old script works too...

Comment: in one table all datas for example IdNr just a Table for IdNr
Here i got a screen: http://piclair.com/wqc3a
A table just for the KNr that has a red border and so much tables as the table has num_fields

Comment: Na now it show the row under KNr but i should just show KNr under KNr and not the full row...

Here so it looks: http://piclair.com/9ptl6

Under KNr just 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

And thanks for ur help.

Comment: It helps :) But it just add 4 extra blank ROWS...
http://piclair.com/v798g